# nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_30'

Tags: matlab, cuda, gpu

I am trying to setup vlfeat/matconvnet on my system. But it give me error when I try to compile GPU files. I am trying their manual. I use both way of compiling, straight and forcing for cuda-6.0 using nvcc as well, but even than that doesn't work.

I have two questions:

1. Is the error because of different driver version and toolkit version ? (I also don't understand why it shows two different)
2. Or is there some other problem. How can I fix it? 
   I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and matlab 2014b.

My gpuDevice information:

```
>>gpuDevice
ans =    CUDADevice with properties:

                  Name: 'GeForce GTX 660'
                 Index: 1
     ComputeCapability: '3.0'
        SupportsDouble: 1
         DriverVersion: 7
        ToolkitVersion: 6
    MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
      MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
    MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
           MaxGridSize: [2.1475e+09 65535 65535]
             SIMDWidth: 32
           TotalMemory: 2.1468e+09
       AvailableMemory: 1.3938e+09
   MultiprocessorCount: 5
          ClockRateKHz: 1032500
           ComputeMode: 'Default'
  GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
      CanMapHostMemory: 1
       DeviceSupported: 1
        DeviceSelected: 1
```

This is the steps i follow:

```
>> vl_setupnn

>> addpath matlab
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: matlab 
> In path at 109
  In addpath at 86 

>> vl_compilenn('verbose', 1)

vl_compilenn: * Compiler and linker configurations *
vl_compilenn:   intermediate build products directory:     /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build
vl_compilenn:   MEX files: /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/
vl_compilenn:   MEX compiler options: -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
vl_compilenn:   MEX linker options: -lmwblas -ljpeg -largeArrayDims
vl_compilenn: * Reading images *
vl_compilenn:   vl_imreadjpeg enabled
vl_compilenn:   image library: libjpeg
vl_compilenn:   image library compile flags: 
vl_compilenn:   image library link flags: -ljpeg
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... connected to 4 workers.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/impl/copy_cpu.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/impl/subsample_cpu.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/impl/im2row_cpu.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/nnfullyconnected.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/nnconv.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/impl/tinythread.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/impl/normalize_cpu.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/impl/pooling_cpu.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/nnbias.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/nnnormalize.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/nnpooling.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents   /MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/nnsubsample.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
"Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/datamex.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/data.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/vl_nnconvt.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/vl_nnconv.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/impl/imread_libjpeg.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
In file included from /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/impl/imread_libjpeg.cpp:14:0:
/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/bits/impl/imread_helpers.hpp:35:2: warning: #warning "SSSE3 instruction set not enabled. Using slower image conversion routines." [-Wcpp]

MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/vl_nnnormalize.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/vl_imreadjpeg.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX CC: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/vl_nnpool.cpp -c -DNDEBUG -largeArrayDims -cxx
Building with 'g++'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX LINK: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex -lmwblas -ljpeg -largeArrayDims /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/vl_nnpool.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/data.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/datamex.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnconv.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnfullyconnected.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnsubsample.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnpooling.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnnormalize.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnbias.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/im2row_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/subsample_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/copy_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/pooling_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/normalize_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/tinythread.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/imread_libjpeg.o
Building with 'gcc'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX LINK: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex -lmwblas -ljpeg -largeArrayDims /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/vl_nnnormalize.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/data.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/datamex.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnconv.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnfullyconnected.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnsubsample.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnpooling.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnnormalize.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnbias.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/im2row_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/subsample_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/copy_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/pooling_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/normalize_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/tinythread.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/imread_libjpeg.o
Building with 'gcc'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX LINK: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex -lmwblas -ljpeg -largeArrayDims /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/vl_nnconv.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/data.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/datamex.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnconv.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnfullyconnected.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnsubsample.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnpooling.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnnormalize.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnbias.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/im2row_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/subsample_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/copy_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/pooling_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/normalize_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/tinythread.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/imread_libjpeg.o
Building with 'gcc'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX LINK: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex -lmwblas -ljpeg -largeArrayDims /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/vl_nnconvt.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/data.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/datamex.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnconv.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnfullyconnected.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnsubsample.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnpooling.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnnormalize.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnbias.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/im2row_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/subsample_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/copy_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/pooling_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/normalize_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/tinythread.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/imread_libjpeg.o
Building with 'gcc'.
MEX completed successfully.
vl_compilenn: MEX LINK: -outdir /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex -lmwblas -ljpeg -largeArrayDims /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/vl_imreadjpeg.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/data.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/datamex.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnconv.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnfullyconnected.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnsubsample.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnpooling.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnnormalize.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/nnbias.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/im2row_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/subsample_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/copy_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/pooling_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/normalize_cpu.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/tinythread.o /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/mex/.build/bits/impl/imread_libjpeg.o
Building with 'gcc'.
MEX completed successfully.
>> vl_compilenn('enableGpu', true)
vl_compilenn:   CUDA: MEX config file: '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/config/mex_CUDA_glnxa64.xml'
Building with 'nvcc'.
sh /tmp/mex_264042254061893_32767: Signal 127
Error using vl_compilenn>mex_compile (line 434)
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_30'


Error in vl_compilenn>(parfor body) (line 393)
  mex_compile(opts, srcs{i}, toobj(bld_dir,srcs{i}), flags.mexcu) ;

Error in vl_compilenn (line 387)
parfor i = 1:numel(horzcat(lib_src, mex_src))

>> vl_compilenn('enableGpu', true, 'cudaRoot', '/usr/local/CUDA-6.0')
Warning: Setting the 'MW_NVCC_PATH' environment variable to
'/usr/local/CUDA-6.0/bin/nvcc' 
> In vl_compilenn at 253 
vl_compilenn:   CUDA: MEX config file: '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/MATLAB/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/config/mex_CUDA_glnxa64.xml'
Building with 'nvcc'.
sh /tmp/mex_264102380876652_32767: Signal 127
Error using vl_compilenn>mex_compile (line 434)
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_30'


Error in vl_compilenn>(parfor body) (line 393)
  mex_compile(opts, srcs{i}, toobj(bld_dir,srcs{i}), flags.mexcu) ;

Error in vl_compilenn (line 387)
parfor i = 1:numel(horzcat(lib_src, mex_src))
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case,you need to modify the cmake command as below:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D CUDA_GENERATION=Kepler ..
```

This is because you install cuda,also you need to check your architecture. The code is only meet the Kepler of architecture of GPU

Answer (score 0):

Checking the supported architectures from section 5.5 (Virtual Architecture feature list) of the [NVCC CUDA Toolkit Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#gpu-compilation) We see that for Kepler, only compute_35 and compute_37 are currently defined virtual architectures.